# show message only in one form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 5 same forms and after I send data to php file using AJAX. If data executed successfully I return message in AJAX success.

```
 success: function (data) {
   $(".suc").html(data);
 }
```

example

```
<form> 1                         <form> 2
<div class='suc'></div>          <div class='suc'>msg </div>
```

if form 2 was submitted I want to send msg only to form2 div.

Comment: Show your event handler .

Comment: I would assume you're running this code in a `submit` event handler on the form, as is best practice, so replace `$('.suc')` with `$(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  Jquery we have `.children () , .parent()  ...etc` methods which help us to select elements inside an element ( like div )
In your case what you need is just to select the .suc class of the form that is submitted . So by using   `.children ()` method  and `$(this)` ( to select which form was submitted ) we can achieve what you are looking !

Use `$(this). children ('.suc').text("sometext")`

**Illustration**

HTML

```
<form class="form" action="" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <h3>FORM 1</h3>
  <div class="suc"></div>
  <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
<br />
<form class="form" action="" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <h3>FORM 2</h3>
  <div class="suc"></div>
  <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

JQUERY CDN

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

JQUERY

```
  $(".form").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    //After  Ajax Success
    // Shoe message in .suc div element of the form which is submitted
    $(this).children(".suc").text("form submitted")
  });
```

Comment: @DorFik Does this answer solves your problem ?

Comment: thanks for the answer. The problem is when submit button pressed in form it takes every form. I have inputs in my forms and to take value which is not empty I needed iterator.

Comment: ok dude. HF I hate my self)). Sorry bothered you. The div element I took out of form. I forgot it) Thank you!!!